# Return OBIEE Subject areas and respected table using Java

Tags: java, obiee

AIM: **My aim was to build logical sql based on presentation subject areas and logical tables.
Is there any way to get list of subject areas and respective tables Columns using any programming language (Java)?** either web services/any nq cmds/ JDBC connection.

I don't want to use ODBC connection because not every machine has install BI server ODBC driver.

from list,I can build logical sql.
Please let me know concerns, I am new to OBIEE world, may be i am thinking in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is: you can use the Web Services. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEIT/bi_server_web_services.htm#BIEIT3235